# Java - Dynamically insert username and password in loop when reading from file

Tags: java, properties, webforms

I dont think this is possible to do, so perhaps I need a totally new way of looking at the problem.

My java program connects to a web form and logs in. I have the username and password form another part of the code.
The HTML form will contain different input types obviously. Depending on the user, and the site, each field will be named differently. Here's a sample web form:

```
<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="/my.form">
Username:
<INPUT NAME="username">
<BR>
Password
<INPUT TYPE="PASSWORD" NAME="password">

<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="my-hidden-name" VALUE="someValue">

<BR><INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Login">
</FORM>
```

In this form, the `NAME` fields can be anything and will change form site to site. I've gotten around this by requiring a `PROPERTIES` file that stores the fields, eg:

```
username
password
my-hidden-name=someValue
SUBMIT=Login
```

This works for half of the above fields. The problem is the `username` and `password` fields.

I already have the username and password, so I COULD just do: `if(currentField=="password") string=mypass123`. but then what if someone makes a form where the username/password field is called `user1` or `passwordField`, or basically anything other than what I've put in the `if()`!!

So, can anyone suggest a way I can handle any combination of names, and still identify which ones are the username and password fields? Here's my current code:

```
//Read file logic here
Properties formProps=getDataFromResource(pathToFormFieldsPropfile);

if(null!=formProps)
{
    //Gets a list of all the field names, eg "username", "password", "submit"
    Enumeration<?> formFields=formProps.keys();
    while(formFields.hasMoreElements())
    {
        String tempString=(String) formFields.nextElement(); //This gets the field name
        query+=tempString   //Will contain field name
                +"="        //Used as a divider in the querystring, ie field=value
                +formProps.get(tempString)  //Value corresponding to field
                //+ URLEncoder.encode((String) formProps.get(tempString),Charset.defaultCharset().toString())   //The value needs to be encoded for POST
                +"&"; //The trailing one of these will have to be removed at the end
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to follow up on this, I managed to come up with a way to fix this, but its probably not ideal.

Basically, I make it so the user must have the username and password as the first and second blank entries in the PROPERTIES file.

Then in my code I have a counter that says, `if ((counter++)==0), insert username` and then `if ((counter++)==1), insert password`, followed by `else leave it blank`.

This works for what I need to do, but may not be ideal.

PS, I implemented a custom Property class to make sure they're all ordered, as the default method stores them in an unordered list.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the *id* element to detect which fields are used for username and password.

Otherwise it sounds like you might need to require that the username and password fields follow some naming convention.

Maybe they could always start with __username and __password (or something like that).

Comment: Sorry, but what is the "id element"?

Comment: Regarding the naming convention, the sites will be already made, so the field names are already there. I suppose if worst comes to worst, I can force them to put username in the PROPERTIES file with an underscore or something prepended, then do the processing, and finally trim the prepended stuff. The problem there is if there exists a website who's fields already start with whatever pattern I've chosen.